# Strange define Error when compiling with 64bit compiler

Tags: c, windows, gcc, x86-64

I tried to use the 64bit MinGW GCC compiler to compile the enigma suite (http://www.bytereef.org/enigma-suite.html).
When I use the 32bit compiler everything works fine. With the 64bit one I get the following error:

```
enigma\global.h|6|error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant|
```

and the line in question is:

```
#define H 0
```

Out of curiosity I changed the line to

```
#define H3 0
```

and it works (of course after changing all appearances). Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

The MinGW 5.1 has header `mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\include\winnt.h`. It contains structure definition with line 6889:

```
DWORD H : 1;
```

Of course, it is a problem if there is higher included header with `#define H 0`.

MinGW 4.8 does not have such structure, so here it can be compiled.

---

The simple fix is to move `#include <windows.h>` on top of `hillclimb.c`